# Coin Change: Existence of a solution to $ax+by+cz = n$ where all variables are positive whole numbers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is it possible to prove the existence of a solution to the equation:
$$ ax + by + cz = n$$
where all variables are whole positive numbers ($x,y,z$ is permitted to be $0$), given $a,b,c,n$.

This is in relation to the coin change problem, in words, this problem should be:

Is it possible to find a combination of coins with values $\{a,b,c\}$ with a total value of $n$?

Comment: Have you tried some concrete examples with small numbers ? Or what have you tried so far ?

Comment: @trueblueanil Essentially I believe the problem boils down to reducing $( (n (mod \ a)) (mod \ b) ) (mod \ c) = 0$, if moduluses of moduluses even is allowed, though it seems my discrete mathematics are lacking.

Comment: What will happen if all the coins have even values, for instance ?